# Magento 2: How to override Block file Configurable.php?

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, overrides

In magento 2, using `Preference` Configurable.php file is not simply override, Is this is magento 2 bug?

I have override simply using preference method inside di.xml file but its not override.

I want to override `function getJsonConfig()` from file. Using only Simply override method of magento 2.
Code for **`di.xml`** file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Block\Product\View\Type\Configurable" type="Package\Configurable\Block\Product\View\Type\Configurable"/>    
</config>
```

Is there any trick or method to override `Configurable.php` file?

Thanks.

Comment: You can use plugin for this.

Comment: without plugin we cant do it? this is simple block file but not override, what is the issue behind this?

Comment: Whole file overwrite is not a good practice. I just add a plugin for you.

Comment: i have created using plugin but in listing page error are available

Comment: can you post answer for overrider getJsonConfig function using plugin, i want to add field qty inside config option for each simple product

Comment: I just posted an answer for you, check now.

Comment: I have one doubt why override functionality is not working for only Configurable.php file, I have override so many block file but only this file are not override, any reason for that?

Comment: @RakeshJesadiya I have the same question now :) do you have an answer for this? I overrode using preference for some price calculation, it is working in view page but not in listing page. Now I am trying to override getJsonConfig using preference, it is not happening at all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**VendorName/ModuleName/etc/frontend/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Block\Product\View\Type\Configurable">
        <plugin name="vendor_configurable_product_configurable" type="VendorName\ModuleName\Block\ConfigurableProduct\Product\View\Type\Configurable" sortOrder="1"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

```
<?php

namespace VendorName\Module\Block\ConfigurableProduct\Product\View\Type;

use Magento\Framework\Json\EncoderInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Json\DecoderInterface;
class Configurable
{

    protected $jsonEncoder;
    protected $jsonDecoder;

    public function __construct(
        EncoderInterface $jsonEncoder,
        DecoderInterface $jsonDecoder
    ) {

        $this->jsonDecoder = $jsonDecoder;
        $this->jsonEncoder = $jsonEncoder;
    }

    public function aroundGetJsonConfig(
        \Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Block\Product\View\Type\Configurable $subject,
        \Closure $proceed
    )
    {
        $config = $proceed();
        $config = $this->jsonDecoder->decode($config);
        $config['url'] = 'sample_url';
        return $this->jsonEncoder->encode($config);
    }
}
```

You can use after plugin following way:

```
<?php

namespace VendorName\Module\Block\ConfigurableProduct\Product\View\Type;

use Magento\Framework\Json\EncoderInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Json\DecoderInterface;
class Configurable
{

    protected $jsonEncoder;
    protected $jsonDecoder;

    public function __construct(
        EncoderInterface $jsonEncoder,
        DecoderInterface $jsonDecoder
    ) {

        $this->jsonDecoder = $jsonDecoder;
        $this->jsonEncoder = $jsonEncoder;
    }

    public function afterGetJsonConfig(
        \Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Block\Product\View\Type\Configurable $subject,
        $config
    )
    {
        $config = $this->jsonDecoder->decode($config);
        $config['url'] = 'sample_url';
        return $this->jsonEncoder->encode($config);
    }
}
```

Comment: Any reason why using the around instead of the after ?

Comment: No reason, You can use after and around both plugin.

Comment: How to do above method using after plugin with same content in above function?

Comment: Its required in after plugin method to pass second parameter as $config?

Comment: @Rakesh The second parameter [$config] is the result of the original method call.

Comment: I think the second line of di.xml should be: <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">

Comment: Can there is any process make this cacheable false?