# Magento 2: How to override configurable.phtml block

Tags: configurable-product, overrides, magento-2.0.7, extend

I am just extended configurable block using a custom block, but I couldn't get the "selected_configurable_option" while changing the configurable options [ not getting simple product id ].

[image]

Did this can be achieved by extending the block like
Block **Test.php**

```
class Test extends \Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Block\Product\View\Type\Configurable{
}
```

**di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"   xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Checkout\Controller\Cart\Add" type="Vendor\MultipleProductsToCart\Controller\Cart\Add" />
    <preference for="Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Block\Product\View\Type\Configurable" type="Vendor\MultipleProductsToCart\Block\Catalog\Product\Test" />
 </config>
```

or do I need to override the configurable.phtml. How to solve this problem ?

Comment: you have to do using Plugin method, you can't override configurable block, but why configurable.php block is not override that' not found yet for me.

Comment: @rakesh can you give some example code to solve this because i am new to magento

Comment: @Rakesh how you add multiple products to cart at one step from product details page

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/122247/magento-2-how-to-override-block-file-configurable-php check this link.

Comment: @Rakesh:  How will we customize configurable block without overriding configurable.phtml, I need to change the view of configurable block to add multiple products to cart also need to add quantity filed for each simple product.

Answer (score 0):

Using a [custom Theme](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-create.html):

1. Create folder `app/design/frontend/<Vendor>/<Theme>/Magento_ConfigurableProduct/templates/product/view/type/options/`
2. Copy the file from `vendor/magento/module-configurable-product/view/frontend/templates/product/view/type/options/configurable.phtml` there
3. Edit as you wish (e.g. add a console.log)
4. Flush Cache Storage

I reckon that is a bit late, but works on Magento 2.1.7

Comment: This is not working in Magento 2.3.1

Comment: This is not working in magento 2.3.1. I am using similar approch to over-write Grouped product info inside  
app/design/frontend/<Vendor>/<Theme>/Magento_GroupedProduct/templates/product/view/type/grouped.phtml. And Grouped product is working but why configurable product is not working using respective file & folder info.

Comment: Worked fine for me in 2.3.5